# Django using a generic view for create_update update_object, form not displaying

Tags: django, python

Trying to use a generic view so I can update an object via a user facing form. My code looks like this in views:

```
from django.views.generic.create_update import update_object

@permission_required('myapp.change_foo', login_url="/accounts/login/")
def foo_update(request, foo_id):
    return update_object(
        request,
        form_class=FooForm,
        object_id=sr_id,
        template_name = 'foo/update.html',
        template_object_name = 'foo',
    )
```

The form definition looks like this:

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    somefield = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

And in my template I have a snippet like this in foo/update.html:

```
    <form action="" method="post"> 
        <table>
            {{ foo.as_table }}
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

I've never had issues displaying 'foo' before, but this is the first time I'm using this particular generic view. No syntax errors, just no form showing up in my template at all.

Does update_object() not embed 'foo' as a form? is it still up to me to add the form add additional content and then write the save() logic for it? I wish there was slightly more documentation on this generic view and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-update-object):

> In addition to extra_context, the template's context will be:
>
> - `form`: A `django.forms.ModelForm` instance representing the form for editing the object. This lets you refer to form fields easily in the template system.

The `template_object_name` argument influences the name of the actual object.

/edit

Jeez, you people... criticizing one of the best documented open source projects out there, but not even trying to read the documentation if it is spoonfed to you. To continue my quote of the docs:

> For example, if the model has two fields, name and address:
>
> ```
>  <form action="" method="post">
>  <p>{{ form.name.label_tag }} {{ form.name }}</p>
>  <p>{{ form.address.label_tag }} {{ form.address }}</p>
>  </form>
> ```
>
> See the forms documentation for more information about using Form objects in templates.

Comment: And I have template_object_name set as 'foo', yet {{ foo.as_table }} isn't showing any output. My example doesn't overlook anything discussed in the documentation.

Comment: you need to write {{ form.as_table }}. You want to output the form as a table, not the object.

Comment: Yes it does. You should pay attention to what both the documentation and piquadrat have written. The *form* is called, not surprisingly, `form`. That is the variable name you should use. `template_object_name` is something else entirely - that is, the object you are editing, not the form.